# TeX Community Polls

Tags: discussion, community

### Welcome to the TeX.SX Community Poll thread!

This thread is used for opinion and usage polls around TeX and [TeX.sx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).
The poll questions are added as "answers" to this "question". Their answers have been added as comments below them. To participate simply up-vote the comments which apply for you. If there is no suitable answer yet simply add it as comment by yourself. You can't up-vote your own comments but the comment author will be counted manually. Please do not add any other comments to these posts. General comments can be added to this "question".

### Rules

- Community poll questions are placed as "answer" posts below. Feel free to add your own<sup>1</sup>.
- Answers to these poll questions are placed as "comments" below them. Because this is also an opinion poll subjective questions are welcome.
  <sub>Please do not ask too specific questions and allow for multiple choices and votes, e.g. instead of something like "My absolute favorite for X is .." use something like "For X I often use ...".</sub>
- To participate up-vote the comments which apply for you.
- If required add a new answer as a comment.
  <sub>If applicable hyperlink the entry to allow other users to learn more about it. Feel free to flag comments for moderator attention if they should be modified for some valid reason (wrong/missing hyperlink, etc.)</sub>
- Feel free to up-vote the poll questions ("answer" posts) as well to indicate that you liked the question. This will push the most favorite questions to the top.
- Do not post any other answer posts or comments. Please provide feedback and critic on the [corresponding discussion thread](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1581/discussion-about-tex-community-polls-if-any) instead.

<sup>1</sup> Should you be affected by the "Trivial answer converted to comment" feature simply post a longer dummy text and then edit it down to the correct content.

Answer (score 74):

My favorite (La)TeX editor is...

Comment: [Vim/GVim](http://www.vim.org/), (Graphical) Vi Improved

Comment: [TeXworks](http://www.tug.org/texworks/), cross-platform open source editor.

Comment: [gedit](http://www.gedit.org), the official text editor of the GNOME desktop environment.

Comment: [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)+[auctex](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/) An extensible customisable text editor

Comment: [textmate](http://macromates.com/) for Mac OS X with the LaTeX bundle

Comment: [TeXnicCenter](http://www.texniccenter.org), a free editor for developing LaTeX documents under Windows.

Comment: [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org), an Aqua-native build of Emacs with AUCTeX already included.

Comment: [TeXStudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/) (a.k.a TeXMakerX)

Comment: [TeXShop](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/) for Mac OS X

Comment: [WinEdt](http://www.winedt.com/) (Windows)

Comment: LyX, a WYSIWYM editor, cross platform

Comment: [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) but _not_ with auctex

Comment: Kile! KDE latex IDE, which rules!

Comment: [Notepad2](http://code.kliu.org/misc/notepad2/)

Comment: [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/), a free cross-platform LaTeX editor.

Comment: geany, a free GTK text editor

Comment: Kile + terminal

Comment: sublime text 2.

Comment: [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/)

Comment: [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (But only for .bib files, otherwise I use emacs or TeXStudio)

Comment: Eclipse with Texlipse plugin

Comment: LEd, Latex Editor, free but unmantained

Comment: Texmaker, geany, Vim/GVim, mcedit

Comment: BaKoMa TeX Word, a cross platform, WYSIWYG LaTeX editor (commercial)

Comment: [Latexian](http://tacosw.com/latexian/), mac-only

Comment: nvi! Nvi is an implementation of the ex/vi text editor originally distributed as part of the Fourth Berkeley Software Distribution (4BSD), by the University of California, Berkeley.

Comment: [FTE Text Editor](http://fte.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Notepad ++ (because I do other stuff with it and I don't want to use many different programs)

Comment: Texpad for Mac OS X

Comment: [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3)

Comment: Vim with [vim-latexsuite](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: [ShareLatex](https://www.sharelatex.com/project) - it's free, and I can't download an editor, so the cloud is much more convenient for me.

Comment: [atom](https://atom.io/) with [language-latex](https://atom.io/packages/language-latex) and [latexer](https://atom.io/packages/latexer)

Comment: I am currently using Atom + language-latex + Atom-latex + latexer + (the perfect git core package) everything in the same spot

Comment: [TeXiFy-IDEA](https://github.com/Ruben-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA)

Comment: [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [LaTeX Workshop extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop).

Comment: Joe editor https://joe-editor.sourceforge.io/

Comment: Leafpad , GTK+ based texteditor

Answer (score 60):

I use the following fonts:

<sup>(Please link to font's page in the font catalogue http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/ which has examples and the necessary code, not to CTAN.)</sup>

Comment: [Latin Modern](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/lmodern/)

Comment: [Computer Modern](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/cmr/)

Comment: [Linux Libertine](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/libertine/)

Comment: [Palatino](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/palatino/)

Comment: [Minion Pro](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minionpro)

Comment: [Inconsolata](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/inconsolata/)

Comment: [Bitstream Charter](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/charter/)

Comment: [Computer Modern Unicode](http://ctan.org/pkg/cm-unicode)

Comment: [The TeX gyre font collection](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/)

Comment: [Antykwa Półtawskiego](http://nowacki.strefa.pl/poltawski-e.html)

Comment: [Lucida](http://www.tug.org/store/lucida/index.html) complete font collection

Comment: [Kerkis](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/kerkis/)

Comment: any of the fonts from [emerald city fontwerks](http://www.speakeasy.org/~ecf/alphabet.htm), provided by the package [emerald](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/emerald/), like `Augie` or `JD`

Comment: [EB Garamond](http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond)

Comment: [League Gothic](http://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/fonts/7-league-gothic)

Comment: [Tulpen One](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Tulpen+One)

Comment: [Bera Mono](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/beramono/)

Comment: [Droid Sans](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/droidsans/)

Comment: [Kpfonts/Kpserif](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/kpserif/)

Comment: [Venturis ADF](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/venturis/)

Comment: [Cambria](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=291) with [Cambria Math](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=360)

Comment: STIX / XITS Math

Comment: [Source Sans Pro](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/sourcesanspro/)

Comment: [_Nexus_](http://www.martinmajoor.com/4_nexus.html) by Martin Majoor. (Commercial.)

Comment: [New Tx](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/newtx/)

Comment: [New Century Schoolbook](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/newcent/) with the `fouriernc` package

Comment: [Baskervald](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/baskervald/)

Comment: [Computer Modern Bright](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/cmbright/)

Comment: [Arev](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/arev/)

Comment: [Times](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/times/)

Comment: Vollkorn by Friedrich Althausen ( http://friedrichalthausen.de/vollkorn/ ), Licensed under OFL.

Comment: [Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMS_Euler) with the [eulervm](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/math.html) package. Usually in combination with Palatino, but occasionally as a text font for headers.

Comment: fourier package

Comment: [Alegreya](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/alegreya/)

Answer (score 52):

I mainly use the following (La)TeX compiler and tool chain:

<sup>(Feel free to add combinations like `latex`+`dvips`+`ps2pdf`)</sup>

Comment: [`pdflatex`](http://www.tug.org/applications/pdftex/) (PDF LaTeX)

Comment: [`xelatex`](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=xetex)

Comment: `latex + dvips + ps2pdf`

Comment: [context](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/context.1.html), a wrapper around [luatex](http://www.luatex.org/) used to compile [ConTeXt Mk.IV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ConTeXt).

Comment: [lualatex](http://www.luatex.org)

Comment: ini-LuaTeX (no fluff LuaTeX)

Comment: latexmk - LaTeX make script in perl

Comment: Makefile with latex+dvips as well as pdflatex output

Comment: [xelatex](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=xetex) controlled by `latexmk`

Comment: xetex (plain ).

Comment: latex + dvips + acrobat (the last is provided by my employer; this is my job)

Comment: rubber (a no longer maintained package on many Linux machines)

Comment: [arara](http://cereda.github.io/arara/)

Comment: [Scons](http://www.scons.org/)

Comment: https://github.com/akerbos/ltx2any

Comment: luatex and optex

Answer (score 49):

I use the TeX distribution ...

Comment: [TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/), the collaborative distribution of TeX user groups.

Comment: [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/)

Comment: [ConTeXt Standalone](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone)

Comment: [MacTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/)

Comment: KerTeX, I do not use on daily basis but it should be mentioned.

Comment: MikTeX portable

Answer (score 44):

I have used the following packages / classes:
(more than once or twice)

<sub>Use format:

`[<name>](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/<name>)`</sub>

Comment: [pstricks](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pst-user.pdf)

Comment: [listings](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf)

Comment: [graphicx](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf)

Comment: [geometry](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf)

Comment: [xcolor](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf)

Comment: [hyperref](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf)

Comment: [hypcap](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/hypcap.pdf)

Comment: [breakurl](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/breakurl/breakurl.pdf)

Comment: [pdflscape](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/pdflscape.pdf)

Comment: [babel](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/babel/babel.pdf)

Comment: [array](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/array.pdf)

Comment: [longtable](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf)

Comment: [tabularx](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/tabularx.pdf)

Comment: [booktabs](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf)

Comment: [multirow](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/multirow/doc/multirow.pdf)

Comment: [multicol](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/multicol.pdf)

Comment: [framed](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/framed/framed.pdf)

Comment: [caption](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf)

Comment: [showexpl](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/showexpl/doc/showexpl-test.pdf)

Comment: [amsmath](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf)

Comment: [pdfpages](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf)

Comment: [cancel](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cancel/cancel.pdf)

Comment: [fancyhdr](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf)

Comment: [calc](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/calc.pdf)

Comment: [printlen](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/printlen/printlen-doc.pdf)

Comment: [needspace](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/needspace/needspace.pdf)

Comment: [fancyvrb](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.pdf)

Comment: [siunitx](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf)

Comment: [microtype](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype)

Comment: [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)

Comment: [csquotes](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes)

Comment: [multido](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/generic/multido/multido-doc.pdf)

Comment: [TikZ/PGF](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf)

Comment: [verbatim](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/verbatim)

Comment: [fixltx2e](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e)

Comment: [xspace](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xspace)

Comment: [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)

Comment: [adjustbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)

Comment: [tikz-timing](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-timing)

Comment: [svn-multi](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/svn-multi)

Comment: [cleveref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref)

Comment: [standalone](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) (class)

Comment: [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)

Comment: [standalone](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) (package)

Comment: [mathtools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)

Comment: [beamer](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer)

Comment: [beamerposter](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamerposter)

Comment: [etoolbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)

Comment: [varioref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/varioref)

Comment: [floatrow](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow)

Comment: [ragged2e](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/raggged2e)

Comment: [pst-pdf](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-pdf)

Comment: [pst-eps](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-eps)

Comment: [pst2pdf](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst2pdf)

Comment: [auto-pst-pdf](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/auto-pst-pdf)

Comment: [textcomp](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textcomp)

Comment: [blindtext](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/blindtext)

Comment: [tipa](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tipa)

Comment: [todonotes](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/todonotes)

Comment: [moderncv](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv)

Comment: [lipsum](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum)

Comment: [KOMA-script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) (classes)

Comment: [scrpage2](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)

Comment: [fontspec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontspec)

Comment: [unicode-math](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math)

Comment: [subfig](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig)

Comment: [xkeyval](http://ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval)

Comment: [xparse](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse)

Comment: [mdframed](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed)

Comment: [minimal](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/minimal.cls) (class)

Comment: [zref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/zref) (incl. `zref-*` packages)

Comment: [soul](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/soul)

Comment: [nag](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nag)

Comment: [parskip](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/parskip)

Comment: [url](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/url)

Comment: [advdate](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/advdate)

Comment: [animate](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/animate)

Comment: [xstring](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/xstring_doc_en.pdf)

Comment: [kvoptions](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/kvoptions.pdf)

Comment: [relsize](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/relsize/relsize-doc.pdf)

Comment: [IEEEtrantools](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf)

Comment: [bm](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/bm.pdf)

Comment: [supertabular](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/supertabular/supertabular.pdf)

Comment: [mhchem](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf)

Comment: [algorithm2e](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/algorithm2e.pdf)

Comment: [glossaries](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf)

Comment: [bookmark](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/bookmark.pdf)

Comment: [datetime](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datetime/datetime.pdf)

Comment: [ifdraft](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/ifdraft.pdf)

Comment: [selectp](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/selectp)

Comment: [rerunfilecheck](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/rerunfilecheck)

Comment: [eurosym](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eurosym)

Comment: [fontenc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontenc)

Comment: [amssymb](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsfonts)

Comment: [amsfonts](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsfonts)

Comment: [cellspace](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cellspace)

Comment: [dsfont](http://mirror.ctan.org/fonts/doublestroke/dsfont.sty)

Comment: [nccbbb](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nccbbb)

Comment: [gensymb](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gensymb)

Comment: [morefloats](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/morefloats)

Comment: [float](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/float)

Comment: [rotating](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/rotating)

Comment: [makeidx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/makeidx)

Comment: [setspace](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/setspace)

Comment: [dcolumn](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn)

Comment: [scalefnt](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/scalefnt)

Comment: [anyfontsize](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/anyfontsize)

Comment: [chemarrow](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemarrow)

Comment: [colonequals](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/colonequals)

Comment: [appendix](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/appendix)

Comment: [hyphenat](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyphenat)

Comment: [footmisc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footmisc)

Comment: [fnbreak](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fnbreak)

Comment: [tocbibind](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind)

Comment: [placeins](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/placeins)

Comment: [nameref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nameref)

Comment: [remreset](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/remreset)

Comment: [picins](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/picins)

Comment: [tocloft](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft)

Comment: [textgreek](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textgreek)

Comment: [hyperxmp](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperxmp)

Comment: [robustindex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/robustindex)

Comment: [attachfile](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/attachfile)

Comment: [alphalph](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/alphalph)

Comment: [pageslts](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pageslts)

Comment: [thumbs](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thumbs)

Comment: [showframe](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)

Comment: [showidx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showidx)

Comment: [showkeys](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showkeys)

Comment: [showlabels](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showlabels)

Comment: [hypbmsec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hypbmsec)

Comment: [chemfig](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig)

Comment: [chemmacros](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros)

Comment: [varwidth](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/varwidth)

Comment: [preview](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/preview)

Comment: [paralist](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/paralist)

Comment: [lastpage](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lastpage)

Comment: [xfrac](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xfrac)

Comment: [sidecap](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sidecap)

Comment: [amsart](http://www.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/amscls.zip)

Comment: [ltugboat](http://www.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tugboat.zip)

Comment: [tugboat (plain)](http://www.ctan.org/macros/plain/contrib/tugboat.zip)

Comment: [wrapfig](http://www.ctan/org/pkg/wrapfig)

Comment: [revtex4-1](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1)

Comment: [pdfcomment](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment)

Comment: [nicefrac](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nicefrac)

Comment: [comment](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/comment)

Comment: [filecontents](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents)

Comment: [docmute](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/docmute)

Comment: [fp](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fp)

Comment: [pgfgantt](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt)

Comment: [struktex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/struktex)

Comment: [bytefield](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bytefield)

Comment: [xifthen](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xifthen)

Comment: [mathdesign](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathdesign)

Comment: powerdot-presenation class based on PSTricks

Comment: pstricks and related

Comment: PSfrag is a LaTeX package that allows one to overlay Encapsulated PostScript ( EPS) figures with arbitrary LaTeX constructions

Comment: cals - a table class similar to HTML tables

Comment: [idxlayout](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/idxlayout)

Comment: [pst-solides3d](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-solides3d)

Comment: [flowfram](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/flowfram)

Comment: [minted](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf)

Comment: [nomencl](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/nomencl?lang=de)

Comment: [imakeidx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx)

Comment: wordlike (to typeset documents that look like were done in word (fonts, titles, headers, etc.)

Comment: [expl3](https://ctan.org/pkg/expl3)

Answer (score 43):

I use (La)TeX on the following platform(s):

Comment: [Ubuntu Linux](http://www.ubuntu.com/) (diverse versions)

Comment: Mac OS X (10.4.x, 10.5.x or 10.6.x)

Comment: Windows 7 (any 'flavour')

Comment: Other Linux distros ([Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org), [Debian](http://www.debian.org), [OpenSUSE](http://www.opensuse.org), [Slackware](http://slackware.com), and so forth.)

Comment: [Gentoo Linux](http://gentoo.org/)

Comment: Windows XP (Prof.)

Comment: Mac OS X 10.7 (Update Joseph's comment?)

Comment: Mac OS X 10.8 (...)

Comment: Windows 8 (any edition)

Comment: Windows / Cygwin

Comment: iOS (on iPad and iPhone)

Comment: Legacy Windows (older than Windows XP).

Comment: Windows XP (Home)

Comment: Windows Vista (any edition)

Comment: OpenBSD since the times of legendary teTeX distribution via TeXLive (ported right after Debian switched from teTeX to TeXLive) and even with KerTeX sometimes.

Comment: Android (all different versions and derivatives )

Comment: Arch Linux (any version)

Comment: Mac OS X 10.9.x

Comment: Windows 10.....

Comment: nixOS Linux (any channel)

Comment: MS-DOS 7.0 [(djgpp)](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/msdos/djgpp)

Comment: Windows 8.1. (Which is not Windows 8.)

Answer (score 42):

I use (La)TeX mainly for ...

Comment: Writing letters

Comment: Writing my PhD thesis

Comment: Writing [project|homework|lab] reports

Comment: Writing articles

Comment: Writing LaTeX packages

Comment: Producing books for conference proceedings or textbook

Comment: Writing conference and journal papers

Comment: Creating presentations (e.g. for conference papers)

Comment: Writing "cheatsheets" to review topics

Comment: Creating vector-graphic-based illustrations

Comment: Writing materials for teaching.

Comment: Manipulating existing PDF documents (such as extracting certain pages, trimming white spaces) with the help of `pdfpages`, `graphicx` packages and an external tool GhostScript directly (or pdfcrop script indirectly).

Comment: Creating an animated image in GIF format. Steps: (1) Create a PDF document consisting a series of pages. (2) Convert the PDF document to a GIF image by using ImageMagick.

Comment: When editing other people's Latex manuscripts.

Comment: Database Publishing

Comment: Fun `:-)` .....

Comment: Publishing theology books.

Comment: Writing a book.

Comment: Creating material for P&P RPG.

Comment: University coursework (Essays, lab reports, assignments, that type of thing)

Comment: answering questions for authors and a publisher's production system (books and journals)

Comment: any time I need to write something.

Comment: writing lecture notes.

Comment: Writing my curriculum vitae/resume.

Comment: Writing anything.

Comment: For earning money.

Comment: Automated generation of reports and catalogues

Comment: Writing tests or exams.

Comment: Writing or editing equations in Stack Exchange posts (in those stacks with MathJaX enabled)

Comment: Controlling long-range missiles remotely.

Comment: Create posters.

Comment: Producing meeting agendas and minutes.

Comment: For all of my litigation documents.

Comment: All sorts of stuff, ranging from papers, to just messing around, to notes.

Comment: Writing my (non-PhD) thesis.

Comment: Writing manuals

Comment: Procrastinating.

Comment: Drawing ducks ? Whaaaaaaaaaaaaa..aaaaaat

Comment: Wasting my time trying to build R tutorials when buying the book and paying someone else to scan and OCR it would cost me less time and money (since time is money).

Comment: Writing software documentation

Comment: Invoking other programs (because I uninstalled my terminal).

Comment: Macro- and expansion-puzzling.

Answer (score 41):

I use the following version control software for my (La)TeX files:

Comment: [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) (`svn`)

Comment: [Git](http://git-scm.com/) (`git`)

Comment: [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) (`hg`)

Comment: [Bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com) (`bzr`)

Comment: none (I don't use any version control software for my (La)TeX files.)

Comment: [RCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_Control_System)

Comment: [CVS](http://www.nongnu.org/cvs/)

Comment: [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/)

Comment: Folders/Compressed files with date or version in their name.

Comment: Numbered backups produced by Emacs in a backup directory.

Comment: Vim + [`undotree`](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree)

Answer (score 38):

I use the following document viewer (to view PDF, DVI, PS and similar files)...

<sub>Please link to the viewer in answers and add the platform for which it is available. This might be interesting for other people. If you use an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)'s viewer write an answer in the form "the viewer of *x*".</sub>

Comment: [Evince](http://projects.gnome.org/evince/) (Linux, mainly Gnome)

Comment: [Adobe Acrobat Reader](http://get.adobe.com/reader/) (Windows, Linux, Mac, ...)

Comment: [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) (OS X)

Comment: [SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/) (Windows)

Comment: [Xpdf](http://foolabs.com/xpdf/)  (UNIX, VMS and OS/2)

Comment: [Okular](http://okular.kde.org/) (KDE/Linux but supports other platforms)

Comment: [Preview.app](http://www.apple.com/macosx/apps/all.html#preview) (OS X)

Comment: [PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) (Windows)

Comment: Adobe Acrobat professional

Comment: The viewer of TeXworks (Windows, Linux, Mac, ...)

Comment: [mupdf](http://www.mupdf.com/)

Comment: [iBook](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ibooks/id364709193?mt=8) (for iPad, iPod, iPhone)

Comment: [xdvi](http://xdvi.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: The [TexMaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) integrated viewer

Comment: [zathura](http://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/)

Comment: [TeXShop integrated Viewer](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/).  This is quite different that the TeXworks viewer.

Comment: pdf.js (the viewer integrated in FireFox since FF19)

Comment: [FoxIT PDF Viewer](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/) Acrobat replacement for Windows, Linux and some smartphones

Comment: [llpp](http://repo.or.cz/w/llpp.git), based on mupdf

Comment: [Qpdfview](https://launchpad.net/qpdfview)

Comment: Yap DVI Previewer (included with [MiKTeX](https://miktex.org/))

Comment: When working with atom, the pdf-view package sometimes

Comment: GSview 5.0 / GPL Ghostscript 9.23 (Windows 95 and Windows 7) for viewing ps and pdf

Answer (score 34):

I create the diagrams for my (La)TeX documents using ...

<sup>Possible choices: TikZ, PGF, PSTricks, xypic, `picture` environment, MS Visio, Inkscape, ...</sup>


<sup>Select 'PGF' if you really using the low level PGF commands, but 'TikZ' if you use that higher level interface.</sup>

Comment: [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/)

Comment: [PSTricks](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/)

Comment: [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: [Metapost](http://tug.org/metapost.html)

Comment: [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/)

Comment: python's matplotlib -> PDF

Comment: [XY-pic](http://www.tug.org/applications/Xy-pic/)

Comment: [Xfig](http://www.xfig.org/)

Comment: Gnuplot with Metapost or other LaTeX compatible output

Comment: [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/)

Comment: [Ipe](http://ipe7.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: [Maple](http://www.maplesoft.com/)

Comment: [epic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/epic) / [eepic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eepic)

Comment: [Gnu R](http://www.r-project.org/)

Comment: I use TikZ and R simultaneously for some figures, with [tikzDevice](https://github.com/Sharpie/RTikZDevice), so I voted for both.

Comment: [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/)

Comment: [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/)

Comment: [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/matlab/) + [matlab2tikz](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz)

Comment: [Google Sketchup](http://www.sketchup.com/)

Comment: LibreOffice Draw.

Comment: [pgfplots](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots)

Comment: [mathematica.se]

Comment: [igor pro](http://www.wavemetrics.com/products/igorpro/igorpro.htm)

Comment: [adobe illustrator](http://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html)

Comment: Microsoft Office

Comment: [Sketch](http://www.frontiernet.net/~eugene.ressler/)

Comment: [Sage](http://sagemath.org/)

Comment: Microsoft Paint Brush (built-in editor in Windows).

Comment: draw.io (online, but can save to your computer)

Comment: [Circuit Macros](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~aplevich/Circuit_macros/) + [some utility](https://github.com/orestesmas/pycirkuit) to convert the source to TIkZ

Comment: [SkiaSharp](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/#:~:text=SkiaSharp%20is%20a%202D%20graphics,graphics%2C%20bitmaps%2C%20and%20text.) together with [CSharpMath.SkiaSharp](https://github.com/verybadcat/CSharpMath/tree/master/CSharpMath.SkiaSharp)

Comment: Sometimes the LaTeX 2e `filecontents*`-environment for creating external .eps-files (text files) and the LaTeX-package epstopdf for converting .eps-file to .pdf on the fly while compiling with an engine that produces pdf output.

Comment: Sometimes [ghostscript/GsView](http://www.ghostgum.com.au/software/gsview.htm) for creating eps/ps-files directly; sometimes GsView 5 or RedMon pdf-printer or the program epstopdf for printing/creating pdf-files.

Comment: Sometimes, but rarely, I use Metafont or [pfaedit/FontForge](https://fontforge.org/) for creating diagrams/images as if they were fonts, but that's sort of painful. ;-)

Answer (score 31):

What do you dislike in (La)TeX?

Comment: (La)TeX syntax and programming style

Comment: Bad error messages.

Comment: Backslashes. Macro expansion. `\expandafter`. Missing data structures.

Comment: Exessive numbers of [] and {}. My pinky hurts after a few hours of coding. This gets much worse when you start using LaTeX inline math instead of $ $

Comment: real utf-8 without extra packages

Comment: nice tables that dont destroy footnotes without extra packages

Comment: long learning curve (I'm not the patient kind...)

Comment: The lack of a proper way to integrate libraries and making them agree on a set of common typesetting goals.

Comment: Compilation is too slow

Comment: Packages that conflict with each other

Comment: To be seen as a geek instead of a cool guy that produces perfect documents ;-)

Comment: Syntax for tables

Comment: Too much attention to "protecting" styles from modification, not enough attention to easy customizability.

Comment: Having few friends who use it or want to use it.

Comment: Too many folders with the same name on many paths.

Comment: Such a pain to draw a diagram. (Seriously, it took me, like, 30 minutes to figure out how to draw a rectangle with a diagonal line across it in TikZ). Though, maybe that's just me.

Comment: Lack of typing, e.g. TeX doesn't complain well enough when I give the wrong arguments to a macro.

Comment: Lack of consistency / intuitiveness in standard macros naming and capitalization. (*e.g.* `\infty` saves 3 letters, but it takes me 5 minutes each time to understand why `\inf` or `\infinity` or `\infinite` don't work out of the box)

Answer (score 30):

I have read the following TeX/LaTeX books:

Comment: *[The TeXBook](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html)* by Donald E. Knuth.

Comment: *[LaTeX -- Das Praxisbuch](http://www.amazon.de/dp/3772363008)* by E. & M. Niedermair, 2003, in German.

Comment: *[TeX by Topic](http://eijkhout.net/texbytopic/texbytopic.html)* by Victor Eijkhout

Comment: *[LaTeX: A Document Preparation System](http://www.amazon.com/LaTeX-Document-Preparation-System-2nd/dp/0201529831)* by Leslie Lamport

Comment: *[The LaTeX Companion](http://www.amazon.com/LaTeX-Companion-Techniques-Computer-Typesetting/dp/0201362996)* by Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goossens

Comment: *[Guide to LaTeX](http://www.amazon.com/Guide-LaTeX-4th-Helmut-Kopka/dp/0321173856)* by Helmut Kopka and Patrick W. Daly

Comment: _[Typesetting Mathematics with LaTeX](http://www.uit.co.uk/BK-TMWL/HomePage)_ by Herbert Voß

Comment: *[Wissenschaftliche Arbeiten schreiben mit LaTeX](http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/3826691024/)* by Joachim Schlosser

Comment: *[LaTeX Beginner's Guide](http://www.amazon.com/LaTeX-Beginners-Guide-Stefan-Kottwitz/dp/1847199860/)* by Stefan Kottwitz

Comment: [Wikibooks latex guide](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/)

Comment: [More Math into LaTeX (4th edn), 2007](http://www.springer.com/book/978-0-387-32289-6), by George Grätzer (Chapter 1 (LaTeX Short Course) [is on CTAN](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/info/Math_into_LaTeX-4/) with supporting examples and videos.)

Comment: [Typesetting tables with LaTeX](http://www.uit.co.uk/BK-TTWL/HomePage), 2011, by Herbert Voss

Comment: [LaTeX line by line](http://www.amazon.co.uk/LATEX-Line-Techniques-Document-Processing/dp/047197918X) by [Antoni Diller](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~ard/) (2nd edn, 1997)

Comment: none - I have not read a book about LaTeX, I just started from some template and whenever there was a problem, I searched the internet

Comment: 'Math into LaTeX' by George Grätzer

Comment: The Not So Short Introduction to LATEX by Tobias Oetiker
Hubert Partl, Irene Hyna and Elisabeth Schlegl

Comment: KOMA-Script, by Markus Kohm and Jens-Uwe Moraski.

Comment: ["Formatting Information"](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/beginlatex/), by Peter Flynn

Comment: "The Joy of TeX", by Michael Spivak

Comment: "A Beginner's Book of TeX", by Silvio Levy and Raymond Seroul

Comment: "The Advanced TeXbook" by David Salomon

Comment: "TeX in Practice", by Stephan von Bechtolsheim

Comment: "TeX for the Beginner" by Wynter Snow.

Comment: [_LaTeX and Friends_](http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/LAF/LAF.html) by Marc van Dongen

Comment: [source2e, The official reference of LaTeX](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) by J.B., D.C., A.J., L.L., F.M., C.R., R.S.

Comment: [LaTeX kézikönyv](http://www.panem.hu/webshop/informatika-szamitastechnika/konnyen-is-lehet/latex-kezikonyv?vmcchk=1) by Wettl Ferenc, Mayer Gyula and Szabó Péter - A quite large, buit comprehensive handbook in Hungarian

Comment: PSTricks: Graphics and PostScript for TeX and LaTeX by Herbert Voss

Comment: The LaTeX Graphics Companion by 
Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, Sebastian Rahtz (Author), Denis Roegel, and Herbert Voss

Comment: [Tout ce que vous avez toujours voulu savoir sur LaTeX sans jamais oser le demander. Ou comment utiliser LaTeX quand on n’y connaît goutte](http://framabook.org/5-tout-ce-que-vous-avez-toujours-voulu-savoir-sur-latex-sans-jamais-oser-le-demander/)

Comment: Does the TikZ/PGF manual count? =P

Comment: [El universo LaTeX](http://www.uneditorial.com/el-universo-latex-incluye-cd-version-interactiva-del-libro-y-software-informatica.html) by Rodrigo de Castro Korgi (in Spanish).

Comment: LaTeX Einführung Band 1 by Helmut Kopka

Comment: [LaTeX appliqué aux sciences humaines](https://latex.developpez.com/tutoriels/latex-applique-sciences-humaines/) by Maïeul Rouquette

Comment: [ConTeXt reference manual](http://pmrb.free.fr/contextref.pdf) by Hans Hagen and Tako Hoekwater

Comment: [The Metafun manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf) by Hans Hagen

Comment: TeX in a Nutshell http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/tex-nutshell.pdf

Answer (score 29):

I'm a member of the user group...

<sup>Please add 'none, I'm not in any (La)TeX related user group.' if it applies.</sup>

Comment: [DANTE](http://www.dante.de/), Deutschsprachige Anwendervereinigung TeX e.V. (German TeX Users Group)

Comment: [TUG](http://www.tug.org/), North American and international TeX Users Group

Comment: [UK-TUG](http://uk.tug.org/): "UK TeX Users' Group"

Comment: [GuIT](http://www.guit.sssup.it/guit/), Gruppo utilizzatori italiani di TeX (Italian TeX Users Group)

Comment: none (I am not a member of any (La)TeX related user groups)

Comment: [GUST](http://www.gust.org.pl) Polska Grupa Użytkowników Systemu TeX (Polish TeX Users Group)

Comment: [NTG](http://www.ntg.nl) Nederlandstalige TeX Gebruikersgroep (Dutch language oriented TeX Users Group)

Comment: [ConTeXt group](http://group.contextgarden.net/)

Comment: [Nordic TeX User Group](http://heim.ifi.uio.no/~dag/ntug/)

Comment: Association GUTenberg (Groupe francophone des Utilisateurs de TeX)

Comment: [CSTUG](http://www.cstug.cz/) Československé sdružení uživatelů TeXu (Czechoslovak TeX Users Group)

Answer (score 28):

My favorite aspects of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems are...

Comment: Beautiful output.

Comment: The combination of programming and typesetting.

Comment: That it's free software/open-source.

Comment: Extensibility, e.g. the possibility to write or rewrite macros.

Comment: Their connection to this site (to participate in this community by using them).

Comment: Maturity and possibly long-term support.

Comment: Stability - TeX doesn't crash and it never destroyed my files.

Comment: That everything is stored in plain text files.

Comment: Input files (in plain text format) can be transmitted over the internet protocol without worrying about security vulnerability.

Comment: The durable value of Knuth's ideas about typesetting.

Comment: It's fun to use

Comment: extensible by its users

Comment: provides abstraction (not least the potential for the separation of content from presentation allows concentration on the logical structure and the content rather than on the appearance)

Comment: Its versatility: articles, books, notes, resumes, presentation slides, sheet music, ... -- one tool for all!

Comment: Their capability for mathematics — the things that (Open)Office and friends simply *can’t do* (let alone do well).

Comment: concentrate on content rather than typesetting

Comment: Potential to extend the degree of automation almost indefinitely.

Comment: Trains my brain: doing some tasks is a complicated combinatorial problem.

Comment: The TeXBook  in which Donald E. Knuth explained TeX with special writing style and order of presenting its contents.

Answer (score 27):

I use TeX mainly in the following academic or professional field:

Comment: Mathematics ...

Comment: Electronic Engineering

Comment: Computer Science

Comment: Philology (languages & literatures)

Comment: Environmental engineering

Comment: Philosophy.....

Comment: Procrastination ;-)

Comment: Linguistics....

Comment: Biology (Plant Science)

Comment: Physics (is too short to be accepted as comment)

Comment: Psychology (Behavioural Sciences)

Comment: Theology ......

Comment: Mechanical Engineering

Comment: Cognitive Science

Comment: Chemistry (is too short to be accepted as comment)

Comment: History .......

Comment: Statistics/Applied Probability/Bioinformatics/Computational Biology

Comment: IT Enterprise Solutions

Comment: Earth Sciences.

Comment: --- Sexology --

Comment: Aeronautical Engineering

Comment: Space Engineering

Comment: Economics.......

Comment: Biomedical/Medical engineering

Comment: Astronomy and Astrophysics

Comment: Engineering Management

Comment: Typography, Document Engineering research

Comment: Religion ......

Comment: Veterinary Sciences

Comment: Chemical Engineering

Comment: Being a student

Comment: Molecular Biology

Answer (score 26):

This poll is used to know the distribution of TeX users based on their nationalities. Please carefully choose only one option per person, don't make a mistake, and someone with administrative privilege might be watching you!

---

There is also a [Data Explorer query](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/99208/world-cup-of-reputation) that uses the information entered in the user profiles. Top ten countries by user numbers as reported on 2023-05-13:

| Country | Number of users |
| --- | --- |
| United States | 7153 |
| Germany | 4917 |
| United Kingdom | 3204 |
| India | 2457 |
| France | 1869 |
| Canada | 1703 |
| Brazil | 1223 |
| Netherlands | 1105 |
| Australia | 952 |
| Switzerland | 890 |

---

Or you can monitor the statistics of this polls at [Top countries of Meta.TeX.SX members](http://data.stackexchange.com/texmeta/query/104312/top-countries-of-tex-sx-members).

Comment: (001) Afghanistan

Comment: (002) Akrotiri .

Comment: (003) Albania .

Comment: (004) Algeria .

Comment: (005) American Samoa

Comment: (006) Andorra .

Comment: (007) Angola ..

Comment: (008) Anguilla .

Comment: (009) Antarctica

Comment: (010) Antigua and Barbuda

Comment: (011) Argentina .

Comment: (012) Armenia .

Comment: (013) Aruba ...

Comment: (014) Ashmore and Cartier Islands

Comment: (015) Australia

Comment: (016) Austria .

Comment: (017) Azerbaijan

Comment: (018) Bahamas, The

Comment: (019) Bahrain .

Comment: (020) Bangladesh

Comment: (021) Barbados .

Comment: (022) Bassas da India

Comment: (023) Belarus .

Comment: (024) Belgium .

Comment: (025) Belize ..

Comment: (026) Benin ...

Comment: (027) Bermuda .

Comment: (028) Bhutan ..

Comment: (029) Bolivia .

Comment: (030) Bosnia and Herzegovina

Comment: (031) Botswana .

Comment: (032) Bouvet Island

Comment: (033) Brazil ..

Comment: (034) British Indian Ocean Territory

Comment: (035) British Virgin Islands

Comment: (036) Brunei ..

Comment: (037) Bulgaria .

Comment: (038) Burkina Faso

Comment: (039) Burma ...

Comment: (040) Burundi .

Comment: (041) Cambodia .

Comment: (042) Cameroon .

Comment: (043) Canada ..

Comment: (044) Cape Verde

Comment: (045) Cayman Islands

Comment: (046) Central African Republic

Comment: (047) Chad ....

Comment: (048) Chile ...

Comment: (049) China ...

Comment: (050) Christmas Island

Comment: (051) Clipperton Island

Comment: (052) Cocos (Keeling) Islands

Comment: (053) Colombia .

Comment: (054) Comoros .

Comment: (055) Congo, Democratic Republic of the

Comment: (056) Congo, Republic of the

Comment: (057) Cook Islands

Comment: (058) Coral Sea Islands

Comment: (059) Costa Rica

Comment: (060) Cote d'lvoire

Comment: (061) Croatia .

Comment: (062) Cuba ....

Comment: (063) Cyprus ..

Comment: (064) Czech Republic

Comment: (065) Denmark .

Comment: (066) Dhekelia .

Comment: (067) Djibouti .

Comment: (068) Dominica .

Comment: (069) Dominican Republic

Comment: (070) Ecuador .

Comment: (071) Egypt ...

Comment: (072) El Salvador

Comment: (073) Equatorial Guinea

Comment: (074) Eritrea .

Comment: (075) Estonia .

Comment: (076) Ethiopia .

Comment: (077) Europa Island

Comment: (078) Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas)

Comment: (079) Faroe Islands

Comment: (080) Fiji ....

Comment: (081) Finland .

Comment: (082) France ..

Comment: (083) French Guiana

Comment: (084) French Polynesia

Comment: (085) French Southern and Antarctic Lands

Comment: (086) Gabon ...

Comment: (087) Gambia, The

Comment: (088) Gaza Strip

Comment: (089) Georgia .

Comment: (090) Germany .

Comment: (091) Ghana ...

Comment: (092) Gibraltar

Comment: (093) Glorioso Islands

Comment: (094) Greece ..

Comment: (095) Greenland

Comment: (096) Grenada .

Comment: (097) Guadeloupe

Comment: (098) Guam ....

Comment: (099) Guatemala

Comment: (100) Guernsey .

Comment: (101) Guinea ..

Comment: (102) Guinea-Bissau

Comment: (103) Guyana ..

Comment: (104) Haiti ...

Comment: (105) Heard Island and McDonald Islands

Comment: (106) Holy See (Vatican City)

Comment: (107) Honduras .

Comment: (108) Hong Kong

Comment: (109) Hungary .

Comment: (110) Iceland .

Comment: (111) India ...

Comment: (112) Indonesia

Comment: (113) Iran ....

Comment: (114) Iraq ....

Comment: (115) Ireland .

Comment: (116) Isle Of Man

Comment: (117) Israel ..

Comment: (118) Italy ...

Comment: (119) Jamaica .

Comment: (120) Jan Mayen

Comment: (121) Japan ...

Comment: (122) Jersey ..

Comment: (123) Jordan ..

Comment: (124) Juan de Nova Island

Comment: (125) Kazakhstan

Comment: (126) Kenya ...

Comment: (127) Kiribati .

Comment: (128) Korea, North

Comment: (129) Korea, South

Comment: (130) Kuwait ..

Comment: (131) Kyrgyzstan

Comment: (132) Laos ....

Comment: (133) Latvia ..

Comment: (134) Lebanon .

Comment: (135) Lesotho .

Comment: (136) Liberia .

Comment: (137) Libya ...

Comment: (138) Liechtenstein

Comment: (139) Lithuania

Comment: (140) Luxembourg

Comment: (141) Macau ...

Comment: (142) Macedonia

Comment: (143) Madagascar

Comment: (144) Malawi ..

Comment: (145) Malaysia .

Comment: (146) Maldives .

Comment: (147) Mali ....

Comment: (148) Malta ...

Comment: (149) Marshall Islands

Comment: (150) Martinique

Comment: (151) Mauritania

Comment: (152) Mauritius

Comment: (153) Mayotte .

Comment: (154) Mexico ..

Comment: (155) Micronesia, Federated States of

Comment: (156) Moldova .

Comment: (157) Monaco ..

Comment: (158) Mongolia .

Comment: (159) Montserrat

Comment: (160) Morocco .

Comment: (161) Mozambique

Comment: (162) Namibia .

Comment: (163) Nauru ...

Comment: (164) Navassa Island

Comment: (165) Nepal ...

Comment: (166) Netherlands

Comment: (167) Netherlands Antilles

Comment: (168) New Caledonia

Comment: (169) New Zealand

Comment: (170) Nicaragua

Comment: (171) Niger ...

Comment: (172) Nigeria .

Comment: (173) Niue ....

Comment: (174) Norfolk Island

Comment: (175) Northern Mariana Islands

Comment: (176) Norway ..

Comment: (177) Oman ....

Comment: (178) Pakistan .

Comment: (179) Palau ...

Comment: (180) Panama ..

Comment: (181) Papua New Guinea

Comment: (182) Paracel Islands

Comment: (183) Paraguay .

Comment: (184) Peru ....

Comment: (185) Philippines

Comment: (186) Pitcairn Islands

Comment: (187) Poland ..

Comment: (188) Portugal .

Comment: (189) Puerto Rico

Comment: (190) Qatar ...

Comment: (191) Reunion ..

Comment: (192) Romania .

Comment: (193) Russia ..

Comment: (194) Rwanda ..

Comment: (195) Saint Helena

Comment: (196) Saint Kitts and Nevis

Comment: (197) Saint Lucia

Comment: (198) Saint Pierre and Miquelon

Comment: (199) Saint Vincent and the Grenadines

Comment: (200) Samoa ...

Comment: (201) San Marino

Comment: (202) Sao Tome and Principe

Comment: (203) Saudi Arabia

Comment: (204) Senegal .

Comment: (205) Serbia and Montenegro

Comment: (206) Seychelles

Comment: (207) Sierra Leone

Comment: (208) Singapore

Comment: (209) Slovakia .

Comment: (210) Slovenia .

Comment: (211) Solomon Islands

Comment: (212) Somalia .

Comment: (213) South Africa

Comment: (214) South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands

Comment: (215) Spain ...

Comment: (216) Spratly Islands

Comment: (217) Sri Lanka

Comment: (218) Sudan ...

Comment: (219) Suriname .

Comment: (220) Svalbard .

Comment: (221) Swaziland

Comment: (222) Sweden ..

Comment: (223) Switzerland

Comment: (224) Syria ...

Comment: (225) Taiwan ..

Comment: (226) Tajikistan

Comment: (227) Tanzania .

Comment: (228) Thailand .

Comment: (229) Timor-Leste

Comment: (230) Togo ....

Comment: (231) Tokelau .

Comment: (232) Tonga ...

Comment: (233) Trinidad and Tobago

Comment: (234) Tromelin Island

Comment: (235) Tunisia .

Comment: (236) Turkey ..

Comment: (237) Turkmenistan

Comment: (238) Turks and Caicos Islands

Comment: (239) Tuvalu ..

Comment: (240) Uganda ..

Comment: (241) Ukraine .

Comment: (242) United Arab Emirates

Comment: (243) United Kingdom

Comment: (244) United States

Comment: (245) Uruguay .

Comment: (246) Uzbekistan

Comment: (247) Vanuatu .

Comment: (248) Venezuela

Comment: (249) Vietnam .

Comment: (250) Virgin Islands

Comment: (251) Wake Island

Comment: (252) Wallis and Futuna

Comment: (253) West Bank

Comment: (254) Western Sahara

Comment: (255) Yemen ...

Comment: (256) Zambia ..

Comment: (257) Zimbabwe .

Comment: (1/0) I refuse to vote.

Comment: Palestine (it's mentioned as West Bank and Gaza, each one in comment!!!!)

Answer (score 25):

Tips that may be regarded as best practices in LaTeX.

Comment: Consider define a macro for a thing that you use repetitively throughout your document so you can modify its setting in one place later and the changes can affect thoroughly.

Comment: Don't manually adjust line breaks and page breaks until you prepare the final version, which means no changes in page layout or font size can be expected.

Comment: Avoid writing a lengthy document in a single input file. Instead, prepare the document structure in advance by creating a separate file for each chapter and/or section and imports them from within a single main input file; This method has some benefits: (1) easing us to rearrange the contents, (2) speeding up the compilation during the development phase by commenting/uncommenting `\input` or by using `\includeonly`.

Comment: Use "code formatting" to make the LaTeX source more readable, such as aligning similar lines in a displaymath environment.

Comment: Read the [Latex obsolete commands pdf](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf) or [Latex Sündenregister, original german version](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/german/l2tabu.pdf)

Comment: Do never put a blank space after a left parenthesis or before a right parenthesis.

Comment: Use structured writing. Use `\include` and `\includeonly` and consider using a folding editor.

Comment: Instead of several-hour struggle with some LaTeX problem, [ask here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: When encountering a problem, quickly extract the actual problem into a minimal working example (MWE), and solve it there, then port the solution back into the whole document.

Answer (score 24):

My favorite document class is...

Comment: scrartcl - an extensive article class of the [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) bundle

Comment: `article` – plain and classic

Comment: `memoir` (for large documents)

Comment: report (for large as well as short documents)

Comment: scrbook of [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script).

Comment: `artikel3` from the [NTG document classes](http://ctan.org/pkg/ntgclass)

Comment: `beamer` for presentations

Comment: `moderncv`, just beautiful.

Comment: `apa` Because I have to.

Comment: `standalone` to test TikZ graphics

Comment: book, just a simple one for lecture notes etc

Comment: `amsbook` (if I write a more comprehensive piece - e.g. PhD thesis)

Comment: `tufte` (for the great layout and font choice)

Comment: `mwe` minimal working example

Comment: `minimal`, just to compile a simple Hello World input file to test whether the installed LaTeX system works.

Comment: `amsart` formats things nicely and automatically loads `amsmath` etc.

Comment: the one I maintain `;)`

Comment: IEEEtran (Too short for comment)

Comment: `revtex` for articles in physics

Comment: `ext-` for changing font sizes of default classes like `article`

Comment: none of LaTeX class

Answer (score 23):

I manage my bibliography using...

Comment: JabRef http://jabref.sourceforge.net/  -- cross-platform standalone bibliography manager.

Comment: [Reftex](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/reftex.html) an emacs plugin

Comment: [BibDesk](http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/) for Mac OS X, included in MacTeX

Comment: a plain text file (directly editing the `.bib` file).

Comment: [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/), a Firefox plugin

Comment: [nbibtex](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/nbibtex/) - Norman Ramsey's substitute for Bibtex that allows a bibliography database to be represented by a set of .bib files.

Comment: [RefBase](http://www.refbase.org)

Comment: [Citavi](http://www.citavi.com/) for Windows, free for databases with up to 100 titles, often free for university students.

Comment: [Bibsonomy.org](http://www.bibsonomy.org/) - a social bookmark and publication sharing system. It has some nice features, among them a JabRef plugin. Biber can even fetch the .bib file from BibSonomy on the fly

Comment: Mendeley.com - A desktop, web and mobile application for handling and sharing your collection of scientific papers.

Comment: [CiteULike](http://www.citeulike.org) - A web based library management solution, with the ability to upload and store documents. Easy to write scripts to automatically download .bib files for particular tags.

Comment: [KBibTex](http://home.gna.org/kbibtex/), a KDE based application

Comment: Bibweb: a utility for automatically retrieving bibliographical information from MathSciNet

Comment: [ebib](http://ebib.sourceforge.net/) for Emacs

Comment: Endnote, and export to bibtex

Comment: The BibMacros package for WinEdt

Answer (score 23):

I find the usage of the following (La)TeX code should be avoided:
<sub>and I'm annoyed seeing other users, especially beginners using it.</sub>

<sub>Expected answers: Most content from `l2tabu`, bad Word-like typesetting, ...</sub>

Comment: `{figure}[H!]` or similar (trying to place a float at the current position; typical behavior of someone coming from MS Word etc.)

Comment: Using LaTeX2.0 style font macros like `\bf`, `\it`, ..., instead of the proper LaTeX2e macros `\textbf`/`\bfseries`, ...

Comment: Misusing math mode to get italic text: `$text$`.

Comment: Using `eqnarray` instead of the math environments provided by `amsmath`

Comment: Inserting a blank line right before & after a displayed equation.

Comment: Using `\begin{center}...\end{center}` instead of `\centering` in `figure` environment.

Comment: Using multiple instances of \\ to make blank lines.

Comment: Using single instances of ``\\`` after each source line to break the output line, too (outside of tables).

Comment: `\"{a}` notation for umlauts instead of utf-8

Comment: $$...$$ for displayed equations

Comment: Using utf-8 for umlauts instead of `\"{a}` notation. @JonasStein Sorry I coudn't resist. What's the problem.

Comment: Using math ellipsis for non-mathematical context such as "I am lazy `$\ldots$`". The correct one is "I am lazy `\ldots`".

Comment: Using `<` and `>` as "angle brackets" instead of `\langle` and `\rangle`.

Comment: Using `"` and `"` as quotation marks instead of `` and `''`.

Comment: Using `\Large` or `\textit{}` inside `\chapter{}` or `\section{}` to format the headings.

Comment: @ Sigur I take it using math mode in headings is a no-go for you as well?

Comment: Using `f : X \to Y` instead of `f \colon X \to Y`

Comment: Making heavy use of `\hspace` and `\vspace`.

Comment: Avoid `\ensuremath`.

Comment: `\documentclass`

Answer (score 23):

What features do you miss in (La)TeX?

Comment: Automatic paragraph flow around arbitrary shapes (like images)

Comment: Autokerning based on the shape of the glyphs

Comment: good multi column support (balancing, images/formulae crossing multiple columns)

Comment: text areas with overflow capabilities ("read more on page 3")

Comment: Output to an "open" format such as InDesign (for editing afterwards) or XML

Comment: Some way of splitting a vbox at a point (should break an image in two parts for example)

Comment: XML input (hey, it's 2011)

Comment: Word's track changes feature. The accept/reject changes functionality blows diff away.

Comment: A real document tree, and a high-level language for arbitrary manipulations thereof – instead of TeX's single-pass traversal and macros.

Comment: More complete implementations of Unicode algorithms and OpenType features.

Comment: A proper grid layout (`\grid` package doesn't work for me).

Comment: JSON input (hey, it's 2013, @topskip)

Comment: Designing support.  You get a book design from a designer and you have to implement it in your document all by yourself.

Comment: Tidier syntax, so that external tools can parse a tex file more easily.

Comment: A proper tool-chain

Comment: `microtype` protrusion and other features working in every use case

Comment: Types, and a type checker. (E.g. dimensions in TikZ can be very confusing, lacking proper error messages.)

Comment: Modular compilation. I don't want to recompile the whole book just because I changed one paragraph. (And no, commenting out `\include`'s or `tikz-externalise` are workarounds, and not solutions.)

Comment: Parallel compilation of beamer slides.

Comment: In addition to macros, arbitrary code/script injection to automate tedious tasks, in arbitrary language.

Comment: Expandable "dynamic" delimited arguments: An expandable primitive where you can pass a delimiter and two <number>-quantities as character codes and then it grabs another argument which is delimited by that delimiter and returns it nested between explicit character tokens of respective character codes of category 1/2. Alternatively  an expandable primitive where you can pass a delimiter nested in braces which grabs another argument which is delimited by that delimiter and returns it nested between such braces as were used for passing the delimiter.

Comment: Expandable comparison of balanced texts for finding out whether the balanced texts compared all consist of the same set of tokens. (As if you would define a temporary macro from each balanced text and do an `\ifx`-comparison to the temporary macros.) Probably this could be combined with first grabbing a <number> quantity for determining how many balanced texts to grab and to compare.

Comment: A way of changing the value of `\globaldefs` only within the current scope even if in the current scope `\globaldefs` currently has a positive value.

Comment: Expandable "lookahead" at the next token.

Comment: Expandable examination of (the shape of) a token so you can find out whether it is an explicit (non-)active character-token/an active character token/a control word token/a control symbol token/whether it is defined in terms of `\long` and/or `\outer`.

Comment: A reliable way of finding out whether two macros do the same: ```\catcode`\|=6 \def\foo#1|2{arg1: |1 arg2: #2}\def\bar|1#2{arg1: #1 arg2: |2}\message{Macros do \ifx\foo\bar equal \else different \fi things.}\bye``` yields "Macros do different things." although `\foo` and `\bar` do the same thing.

Comment: The ability to get multiple documents into a single .pdf file/output-file in one LaTeX run. And in doing so, for example, between documents, reset things like the counter for page-numbers that appear visibly on the paper. (This would be interesting, e.g., if you have multiple documents/forms in a single fillable pdf-file and at the time of filling out the form wish entries in form-fields in one document to appear entered in the other document as well.)

Comment: The possibility of creating more than one output-file/pdf-file within one compilation of .tex-input. (That would conjure up other desires, such as wanting an interface where you can decide what things you define/set for which .pdf output files.) This might make creating cross-links between different pdf-files more easy.

Comment: A mechanism which truly turns a command that does not produce visible output into something that does not affect typesetting. (All variants of LaTeX's `\@bsphack`..`\@esphack` known to me have more or less subtle drawbacks.)

Comment: A prefix `\word` similar to `\global`/`\long`/`\outer`/`\protected`  so that after `\word\def\MacroHoldingWords{...}` TeX does not switch the status of the reading apparatus to state S but does switch it to state M after tokenizing an instance of the argumentless control word token `\MacroHoldingWords` so that spaces after that control word token will not be ignored. This way the xspace-workaeound would not be needed when defining a control word token to deliver some words whereafter a space in the .tex-input should not be ignored.

Comment: A possibility to change the endline-character at the time of pre-processing already appended to the characters of the current line. This would be useful for handling the first line of an xparse-`+v`-type argument while in expl3-mode where `\endlinechar` is 0 so that the first line of the argument won't be handled properly and stuff in the last line not belonging to the +v-argument any more will have the +v-endline-character (^^M) appended.

Answer (score 22):

My favorite aspects of [TeX.sx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) are...

Comment: The amount of knowledge in the community.

Comment: The high activity on the site (quick answers, frequently multiple answers, quality control through votes and comments)

Comment: The possibility to always learn more about (La)TeX even if you already know a lot.

Comment: To be able to see how other people create documents and solve issues (which can be sometimes completely different to your way).

Comment: The nice and easy modern interface for writing, editing, commenting and searching.

Comment: How friendly it is. No matter how archaic or random my questions is I still get good answers, and people accept me in the chat, despite the fact that everyone else there has forgotten more LaTeX then I know.

Comment: Practising my (La)TeX skills in areas I don't normally use.

Comment: Calling "procrastination" "help".

Comment: I wanted to say a big THANK YOU. I had to produce a class file for my students for their third year report, and I wanted to make things as simple as possible for them. I had many unresolved problems as I am no expert, but every single question was answered on the site. Without the help given by the experts on this site I would simply have abandoned my endeavour. THANKS AGAIN.

Comment: Keeping track of problems still unresolved after 4 years.

Answer (score 20):

To a total LaTeX beginner (not TeX in this case) I would recommend to start learning LaTeX by reading first ...

<sub>Books, online howtos, ...</sub>

Comment: [The (Not So) Short Introduction to LaTeX2e.](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/)

Comment: [LATEX for Word Processor Users](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/latex4wp/latex4wp.pdf)

Comment: [L'Arte di Scrivere con LaTeX](http://www.lorenzopantieri.net/LaTeX_files/ArteLaTeX.pdf) (It's in Italian, though.)

Comment: [LaTeX and Friends](http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/LaTeX-and-Friends.pdf) by Marc van Dongen

Comment: [LaTeX -- Das Praxisbuch](http://www.amazon.de/dp/3772363008) by E. & M. Niedermair, 2003, in German.

Comment: [LaTeX Beginner's Guide](http://www.packtpub.com/latex-beginners-guide/book) by Stefan Kottwitz

Comment: [More Math into LaTeX (4th edn), 2007, by George Grätzer](http://www.springer.com/new+%26+forthcoming+titles+%28default%29/book/978-0-387-32289-6) (Chapter 1 (LaTeX Short Course) [is on CTAN](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/info/Math_into_LaTeX-4/) with supporting examples and videos.)  (Thanks to [mas](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/users/6964/mas) for the link info [in his comment here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/tex-community-polls/1574#comment4208_1571))

Comment: @TomBombadil: Be sure to get _that_ edition. The recent ones are written with Word. :-(

Comment: [LaTeX for Complete Novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/novices-report.pdf) by [Nicola Talbot](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862)

Comment: [El universo LaTeX, 2nd ed](http://www.uneditorial.com/el-universo-latex-incluye-cd-version-interactiva-del-libro-y-software-informatica.html) by Rodrigo de Castro Korgi (for Spanish language LaTeX apprentices).

Answer (score 18):

What small mistakes that you have done make (La)TeX stop working?

Comment: Using `\tiny` and `\bf` in `minimal` document class.

Comment: Using `pdflatex` to compile an input file that either imports EPS or contains PSTricks code.

Comment: Using `latex.exe` to compile an input file that imports PNG, PDF or JPEG images.

Comment: Programmed a recursive macro with a faulty abort mechanism.

Comment: Forgot a semicolon inside a TikZ picture

Comment: Forgot to add `fragile` option to Beamer's `frame` environment that contains verbatim blocks.

Comment: Tweak the source code of pdftex with too little understanding of Pascal or the Web programming language.

Comment: Confusion between length macros that need \ and counter macros that don't need \ leads us to make mistakes such as typing `\setlength{paperwidth}{10cm}` or `\setcounter{\enumi}{10}`.

Comment: Forgot `\\\` somewhere in a table.

Comment: Didn't know the difference between TeX and LaTeX. (Undefined control sequence `\documentclass`...)

Comment: Introduced a small bug into `\fbox` that stopped it working for everybody. 
1994-06-06 David Carlisle <latex-bugs@latex-project.org>

 * ltboxes.dtx: Fix bug introduced last week. Add \leavevmode to
   \fbox, and make \long. At the same time make \sbox and \mbox
   \long even though they were not \long in 2.09.

Comment: Gave a macro less arguments than it needs.

Comment: Unbalanced `\if` constructs.

Comment: created a "circular" macro; of course tex didn't *stop* -- i had to crash it manually.

Comment: put in too many open braces/groups, or not enough closing ones; also, mismatched `$` signs.  either one can get you out of synch really fast!

Comment: Running `...latex myclass.cls` or `...latex mypackage.sty`

Comment: `\newif` inside `\if... ... \else ... \fi`

Comment: Using `{}` instead of `[]` for optional arguments of macro and `[]` for mandatory arguments, and forgetting which arguments are mandatory and  which are optional.

Comment: Forgot to escape _ (e.g. in URLs)

Comment: Updated TeX Live

Comment: Forgot a comma to separate `\tikzset` `.style` definitions, the compilation loops!

Comment: Forgot to end a line with `%` to remove unwanted space being passed along (e.g. last item in a `\foreach` list)

Comment: Added some text (not even a mistake) and caused a float to get lost.

Comment: Define a macro whose name was already taken by something I did never know about.

Comment: Minor permutation in a long series of `\expandafter\def\csname\noexpand\fi\endcsname\edef\expandafter\expandafter\noexpand\foreachitem\global\let\expandafter\csname\endgroup\def\if\xdef\..`

Answer (score 16):

What small mistakes that you have made allow (La)TeX to continue working, but produce an unexpected result?

The objective of this poll is to collect mistakes that are frequently made by us (especially for the beginner).

Comment: Forgot to append a trailing `\ ` or `{} ` right after a macro that eats white spaces. For example writing `\LaTeXe is...` will produce "LaTeX2eis" instead of "LaTeX2e is".

Comment: Forgot to add a `%` to remove unnecessary white spaces.

Comment: Forgot to prefix a period following a capital letter with `\@` such that the period is intended to end a sentence.

Comment: Forgot to append a period following a non-capital letter with `\ ` such that the period is supposed not to be the end of sentence.

Comment: Kept subversion conflict markers (`<<<<<<<<<`) in the text body

Comment: Misspelled label name in either `\label`, `\ref` or `\cite`.

Comment: Forgot to specify non-breaking space with `~` (e.g. `Figure~\ref{fig:somefig}`.

Comment: Hoping `$\tiny abc$` (font size change in math mode) can produce the expected result. Actually it will never work because  the developers chose to disable font changing commands inside formulas.

Comment: Forgot to use `\ignorespaces` when we use `\noindent` (or `\indent`) at the end of a macro with arguments.

Comment: A wrong placement of `\noindent`. For example `\par\noindent\vspace{\baselineskip} <text>` that should be `\par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent <text>`.

Comment: Forgot to end the paragraph with `\par` before the closing `}` in `{\Huge long text spanning 2 or more lines}`.

Comment: Using `longtable` inside `table` environment because of a wrong assumption that `longtable` is long version of `tabular`. The same syntax and column specifiers lead us to this wrong assumption.

Comment: Used `\label` before `\caption`, so that the referencing of the Float did not work as expected.

Comment: Forgot to put a *backslash* before "underscore and ampersand (symbol)"

Comment: Trying to pass an argument to a switch-type command that would need grouping instead: `\command{...}` instead of `{\command ...}`

Comment: Used `$` inside `\ensuremath`: `\ensuremath{$x+y=z$}`. In short: I used `\ensuremath`. ;->

Answer (score 16):

As a TeX user, I favour

1. [**logical punctuation**](http://www.slate.com/articles/life/the_good_word/2011/05/the_rise_of_logical_punctuation.html), a.k.a. "British style"; or
2. **rhetorical punctuation**, a.k.a. "American style."

The following example, taken from Edward D. Johnson's *The Handbook of Good English* (Simon & Schuster, 1991), illustrates the difference between the two:

*I'm not sure what is meant by 'fail-safe'*. (logical punctuation)

*I'm not sure what is meant by 'fail-safe.'* (rhetorical punctuation)

Comment: logical punctuation

Comment: In my language, German, only logical punctuation exists. I did not knew there were other styles up until now. The rhetorical style looks ugly and wrong.

Comment: logical, for sure.  if you've ever been burned by having an unenlightened editor (person) insist that the period (or comma) be placed inside the quotes that delimit a typing command instruction, you wouldn't accept any other option.  that was the situation that permitted a change in tex-related user manuals at ams.  (i can't speak for other publications, but at least we're freed from questions about why something doesn't work when directions were followed to the letter/punctuation symbol.)  likewise for tugboat.  logic rules.

Comment: rhetorical punctuation

Comment: Logical punctuation, because the full stop [period] belongs to the whole sentence, not just the term in quotes. IMNSHO, rhetorical punctuation lives in the same cave as "rhetorical dates", the ones where the day comes *between* the month and the year...

Answer (score 15):

On which other *stackexchange* sites you are a member? (Let's say being a "member" means ask a question or provide an answer there.)

The comment format should be:

```
[TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/)
```

Comment: [Meta.StackOverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: [English Language and Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com)

Comment: [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com)

Comment: [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: [RPG](http://rpg.stackexchange.com)

Comment: [History](http://history.stackexchange.com)

Comment: [Chemistry](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com)

Comment: [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Comment: [Ask Ubuntu](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com)

Comment: [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: Unix and Linux SE.

Comment: [Academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: [Travel](http://travel.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: [Scifi+Fantasy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) (English Language Learners)

Comment: [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: [Linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: [Cryptography](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/) (cooking)

Comment: [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com)

Comment: mathoverflow.com

Comment: [Joomla!](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: [Vi & Vim](http://vi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: [Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: [Vegetarianism](http://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com)

Comment: [Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 13):

I found [TeX.sx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) via...

Comment: some search engine.

Comment: StackExchange menu on the top.

Comment: Migration from StackOverflow.

Comment: Area 51 (participated on the private beta)

Comment: Via Joseph Wright's blog [Some TeX developments](http://www.texdev.net/2010/08/02/a-new-place-for-tex-questions/).

Comment: Am I supposed to remember this?

Comment: Some comment in comp.text.tex

Comment: Migration from [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net)

Comment: Area 51 (didn't participate in the private beta).

Comment: I liked formatting the equations on the physics.SE and was messing with detexify, and then I was like, hmmm, maybe I should learn more about this, it's so fun.

Answer (score 13):

How is your activity or behavior on this site?

Comment: I read all questions of one topic and try to answer most of them.

Comment: I try to read all questions unless I know I'm not interested and not able to provide any support.

Comment: I only read several new questions on that day.

Comment: I scan for things I'm likely to be able to answer.

Comment: I read questions that are likely to be of interest to me

Comment: I use subscriptions on several tags that alert me of questions of possible interest.

Comment: I don't read the questions and answers. Instead I am just logged in the chat room for fun.

Comment: I am only interested in reading old unanswered questions that are randomly poked by the bot [Community](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community).

Comment: I only ask questions. I am not knowledgeable enough to provide answers.

Comment: I always collect and save reputation and don't want to spend them for bounties.

Comment: I mostly search and ask for current problems I have. May find the occasional question I can answer, or post my own question-answer pair.

Comment: I will see what I can learn from questions in chat. Sometimes I answer questions on the site, only to find on refresh that egreg and davidcarlisle has pounced the question a couple of seconds later, deleting my answer, and skulking further in the shadows.

Comment: I mostly ask questions.

Answer (score 13):

I use **Windows** and the **TeX Distribution** ...

<sub>Since Windows users are the only ones who have MiKTeX as an option, I thought it'd be interesting to see how the user distribution between and MiKTeX and TeX Live *on Windows* is. See also [the cross-platform question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1565/4012).</sub>

Comment: MiKTeX ........

Comment: TeX Live ......

Comment: `putty` to my school server (yes, I really do it).

Comment: KerTeX on Cygwin

Comment: teTeX on Cygwin (Actually a few times I had to use Windows in my life that is how I used TeX).

Answer (score 12):

Have you found an error in any of [Donald Knuth's publications](http://sunburn.stanford.edu/~knuth/books.html) for which you were rewarded?

Comment: No, I have not.

Comment: No, not yet! (still looking)

Comment: yes, several.  my favorite was an extra space in a texbook running head, noticeable only by the fact that it didn't line up with the text margin.  (confession: i sometimes get to look at proofs of tex-related material before publication, so nobody else gets a chance to find errors that i see first.)

Comment: No, never! (still looking only for answers)

Comment: Yes! Error in the link itself: `sunburn.stanford.edu’s server IP address could not be found.`.

Comment: [all is error](https://xkcd.com/816/)

Answer (score 12):

TeX related releases I look forward to...

Comment: [LaTeX3](http://www.latex-project.org/latex3.html)

Comment: [TeXLive 2011](http://www.tug.org/texlive/) (now released, please still vote for it if you were looking forward to it)

Comment: Ubuntu packages for TeXLive 2010/11.

Comment: Faster `XeLaTeX`.

Comment: The new version of that package I'm already writing on for quite some time.

Comment: [LuaTeX 1.0](http://www.luatex.org)

Comment: TeX Live 2012 (on the way).

Comment: TeX Live 2013 (At some point we should just say 'the next version of TeX Live)

Comment: MikTeX 3.0 (or simply the next MikTeX, to keep it general)

Comment: the next version of TeX Live

Comment: don knuth's 2013 update to tex, metafont. and errate to *computers & typesetting*.

Comment: Someone who collects the legacy of TikzEdt.

Answer (score 11):

Beside TeX.sx I regularly visit/participate in the following (La)TeX related websites / blogs / mailing lists ...

<sub>Please add a link and a short description.</sub>

Comment: [comp.text.tex](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.text.tex) - TeX Usenet Group

Comment: [LaTeX Matters](http://texblog.wordpress.com/) - private blog

Comment: [PhilTeX](http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/) - Technology for Philosophers - A Group Blog

Comment: [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org/)

Comment: [TeXExample.net :Community](http://www.texample.net/community/) Aggregate of blog entries on TeX

Comment: [TeX on Mac OSX Mailing list](http://email.esm.psu.edu/mailman/listinfo/macosx-tex)

Comment: [XeTeX Mailing List](http://www.tug.org/mailman/listinfo/xetex)

Comment: [GuIT Forum](http://www.guitex.org/home/) (in Italian)

Comment: [ConTeXt Mailing List](http://www.ntg.nl/mailman/listinfo/ntg-context)

Comment: [de.comp.text.tex](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/de.comp.text.tex)

Comment: [KOMA-Script Documentation Project](http://www.komascript.de)

Comment: tex-d-l - a german language tex discussion list

Comment: http://planet.dante.de/

Comment: [fr.comp.text.tex](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/fr.comp.text.tex)

Comment: [texhax Mailing List](http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/texhax)

Comment: [ctan](http://www.ctan.org/) and [tug](http://www.tug.org/)

Comment: [PSTricks.tug.org](http://PSTricks.tug.org)

Comment: [pstricks.blogspot.com](http://pstricks.blogspot.com)

Comment: [LaTeX Users Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!forum/latexusersgroup) (on Google Groups)

Comment: [/r/LaTeX](http://www.reddit.com/r/latex)

Comment: I don't partecipate in other forums because they seem to me less clear than TeX.SE.

Comment: [texnique.fr](https://texnique.fr/osqa/)

Comment: [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)

Comment: [TopTeX](https://topanswers.xyz/tex)

Answer (score 9):

I'm using (La)TeX also for the following other applications besides writing actual full documents:

<sub>Expected answers: Rendering math, creating diagrams to import into other software, ...</sub>

Comment: Creating standalone diagrams which are converted to images (PNG, SVG, PDF, ...) for a web application.

Comment: To insert math and diagrams into my blog (e.g. using [QuickLaTeX](http://www.quicklatex.com/)).

Comment: Manipulating existing PDF documents (such as extracting certain pages, trimming white spaces) with the help of `pdfpages`, `graphicx` packages and an external tool GhostScript directly (or `pdfcrop` script indirectly).

Comment: As a calculator, using one of the many fixed/floating point packages out there.

Comment: writing (pseudo) LaTeX code in emails for exchaning mathematics

Comment: answering author questions, repairing their mistakes, and correcting their misconceptions

Comment: writing a couple of regular columns for tugboat.

Comment: Formatting lists of publications to be inserted in web sites using a custom made `bst` to output `html` code.

Comment: Typing formulas on my web pages with a little help from MathJax

Comment: For math formulas on my PmWiki's with a little help from MathJax.

Comment: For mathematics formulas when I use text2tags light markup to type documents.

Comment: Making posts on [cs.SE], [math.SE] and others readable.

Comment: Creating standalone vector diagrams programmatically (not for web application in particular).

Comment: Creating [memes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrAnQ.jpg).

Answer (score 8):

What is the strangest thing you have used *TeX for?

Comment: [Making props for my Pen and Paper Call of Cthulhu game](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29402/7880) and the  [Finished Product](https://canageek.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/summon-invisible-servant/)

Comment: creating a profile pic for myself on tex stack exchange

Comment: typographic experiments - whatever you understand by that `:)`

Comment: Creating the favicon for my personal website

Comment: creating and compiling symbol lists to be considered for addition to unicode.

Comment: [Duplicating plain text files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89273/19356).

Comment: Decoding christmas songs.

Comment: Typing music scores

Comment: Generate roman numerals to test the solution of an exercise for a programming class.

Comment: Draw a diamond!

Comment: Write greeting cards.

Comment: Design background picture for [a local band poster](http://www.lejam.com/mango-duck-tremplin-jam-lois-hammel-ladies-jam-one-guyles-paillotes-du-jam/).

Answer (score 8):

How do you prepare the TeX input file?

Comment: I slowly type it with 2 fingers while looking at the keyboard.

Comment: I type it with 10 fingers and without looking at the keyboard.

Comment: for macros, i steal as much as i can, cutting and pasting from working code, and adapt and extend as necessary.

Comment: i type it with 10 fingers, but do find it advisable to look at the keyboard.

Comment: if submitting to a particular publication, i look for their template, and start with that if one is available; otherwise, i look for their sample files, and copy the structure from there to start.

Comment: I type with 10 fingers without looking at the keyboard whilst still being capable of finding all keys, including the Shift Key.

Comment: As nicely as possible.

Comment: Sitting on a chair.

Comment: Lying in my bed.

Comment: Typing, thinking, smoking, chatting and sipping coffee in random order.

Comment: Ask somebody else to do it for you.

Comment: Clicking a virtual keyboard with two mice --- one for each hand.

Comment: Painfully sometimes.

Comment: Use my personal template/snippet then correcting it because it is not adapted to this very case.

Answer (score 8):

Which answer (not question) do you like most?

Please use the following format

```
[<title>](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/<id>)
```

rather than

```
[<title>](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/<id>/<hyphenated title>#<id>)
```

Comment: I think this topic didn't have the attention it deserves, why don't you ask a new question on Meta TeX.SE?

Answer (score 8):

Which keyboard layout do you use?

- QWERTY?
- Some national layout (AZERTY, QWERTZ, Neo)?
- Some Dvorak variant (original, Simplified, Programmer)?
- Colemak?
- ...

---

<sup>Related: [Good keyboard layouts for typing (La)TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1979/good-keyboard-layouts-for-typing-latex)</sup>

Comment: Programmer Dvorak

Comment: qwerty (but sometimes a "restricted" version)

Comment: QWERTZ. It’s just a question of familiarisation, especially for all the important TeX keys (`\{}[]`) and, important for MarkDown, also the backtick `.

Comment: [Neo](http://neo-layout.org/)

Comment: qwerty (`us_intl/altgr`) layout on a keyboard with its keys physically labelled as qwertz.

Comment: [QWERTY (Finnish multilingual)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#Finnish_multilingual)

Comment: I would like to try other.

Comment: [bépo](http://www.bepo.fr)

Answer (score 6):

What's your first full TeX/LaTeX document? There can be multiple options (full thesis/book/..).

Comment: Academic Thesis

Comment: a catalog of math books and journals, prepared using plain tex, using purpose-built macros, with content translated from another typesetting system by a purpose-built converter, and edited to clean up the last ugly bits.  my first *original* document was a short article for tugboat; however, i did also create the first (plain tex) document style for tugboat, so maybe that counts.

Comment: Final Year Project Thesis (german "Diplomarbeit")

Comment: First Thesis (italian "tesina"), here is the title: *Quantum Chemistry of Vision: photo-isomerization in Bacteriorhodopsin Retinal*.

Comment: MSc thesis.....

Comment: Research paper.

Comment: School report (undergraduate).

Comment: Lecture notes from Literature at my middle-school, grade 8 IIRC, I was like 14 back then ;)

Comment: Scientific report for a summer job I had.

Comment: Typing up some stuff for my dad (results from a simulation he did, with graphs and equations and all that jazz).

Comment: Private maths research

Comment: Handout for students.

Comment: An article for a high school newspaper.

Answer (score 5):

What packages have you used (at least once) and they must be used with `-shell-escape` to work?

Use the following format: `[<package name> ](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/<package name>)`

Comment: [ifplatform](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ifplatform)

Comment: [auto-pst-pdf](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/auto-pst-pdf)

Comment: [pstool](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pstool)

Comment: [gnuplottex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gnuplottex)

Comment: [filter](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/context-filter)

Comment: tikz (with gnuplot)

Comment: [minted](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minted)

Comment: [gregorio](https://gregorio-project.github.io/), for Gregorian chant.

Comment: TikZ externalize

Comment: imakeidx (sometimes with `[original]`)

Answer (score 5):

Which question (not answer) do you like most?

Please use the following format

`[<title>](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/<id>/<id>)`

rather than

`[<title>](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/<id>/<hyphenated title>)`.

Comment: I think this topic didn't have the attention it deserves, why don't you ask a new question on Meta TeX.SE?

Answer (score 4):

The **package** I was not aware of but after discovering it saved my life is...

Comment: subfiles ~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: `yax` saved my life a few times even though I'm a PGF junkie.

Answer (score 3):

*This poll is intended for those give commercial services as professional "(La)TeX and Friends" consultants. If you are not in this category please kindly and honestly don't participate.*

What do you think about the presence of this Q&A site (tex.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: It makes our jobs reduced significantly because people can get satisfied answers from it free of charge.

Comment: It disturbs our income (financial condition).

Comment: It eases our work because many clients are not familiar with TeX.SX while we are and can use it to solve the tasks and get help.

Answer (score 1):

When will you retire from this site?

Comment: When David stops eating pineapple pizzas.

Comment: When this site is closed for good.

Comment: When a new document preparation language with nicer syntax and easy-to-use high-level programming concepts will eventually replace LaTeX.

Comment: When singularity happens.