# What is the highest voted comment on TeX.SE?

Tags: discussion, comments, score

I just came across this

> In an ideal world the workflow would be "1) tell your collaborators to use LaTeX 2) live happily ever after"

[comment by Seamus](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/workflow-for-converting-latex-into-open-office-ms-word-format#comment6123_4145) and thought "wow, I haven't seen a comment with so many upvotes so far." So I wondered what the comment with the most upvotes on TeX.SE was.

Answer (score 15):

The [current highest-voted comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/how-do-i-make-my-document-look-like-it-was-written-by-a-cthulhu-worshipping-madm#comment57793_29402) has a score of 208:

[image]

You can run [a SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/795241/top-100-highest-voted-comments) to see the top 100 highest-voted comments.

Comment: I forked your query to add authors (of comments and posts): http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/795349/top-100-highest-voted-comments

Comment: Contrary to my expectations, most of the highly voted comments are not purely humorous.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, Werner is not completely right. The thing is, the highest voted comment is on Meta.TeX.SE, namely at [TeX Community Polls](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/tex-community-polls/1565#comment3702_1565)

> [TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/), the collaborative distribution of TeX user groups.

Comment: True. It's technically a comment, but actually, it's an answer, since the question is a community poll. ;)